# Could someone explain me the below code, Not able to understand how it takes each elements from the dataframe and checks it

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, detection

```
def detection_error(element):
    try:
        float(element)
    except ValueError:
        return element
    
print(df["Annual Salary"].apply(detection_error).loc[df["Annual Salary"].apply(detection_error).notna()].values)
```

Not able to understand how it takes each elements from the dataframe and checks it

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no `return` statement in the `try` block of the `detection_error()` function. So if the attempt to convert `element` to float is successful, the function returns `None`. Otherwise it returns the element unchanged.

If the function is applied to the elements in a dataframe, you can thus filter the elements that the function was not able to convert with `notna()`, because they are not `None`.

For numerical columns, pandas will store `None` values as `np.nan`, but that does not change the result of `notna()`.